# Is polling for document.body an acceptable alternative to the DOMContentLoaded event?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, document, document-body, domcontentloaded

I initially wrote a bunch of code using `DOMContentLoaded` with `addEventListener`, then `attachEvent`, `onreadystatechange` / `(doScroll)` for old IE / Opera, with a fallback to `window.onload = function(){...}`. But upon thinking about it, there seems to be a much simpler way: just check if `document.body` is not `null` or `undefined`. Are there any caveats to using this approach besides not having the `Event` object available? Because this has worked perfectly so far as a bare-bones approach:

```
function checkReady(func) {

    function checkBody() {
        if (document.body) { clearTimeout(x); func.call(document) }
    }
    var x = setTimeout(checkBody,10);

}
checkReady(function() {

    console.log(this.body.childNodes);

});
```

Comment: Doesn't a page in the process of loading have the `<body>` tag anyway, even if it hasn't been fully populated? Listening for the event is a *lot* more elegant as well. You could also consider ditching the listener and just giving the script tag the `defer` attribute, or put it at the bottom of the `<body>`

Comment: Not if you put your `<scripts>` in the `<head>`. Try adding `(console.log(document.body.childNodes))` to an inline script in the head `// TypeError`

Comment: Sure, while the browser is loading in the `<head>`, the `<body>` won't exist yet, but immediately after that, the `<body>` may well exist, despite not having loaded much of its content - you can see this often enough on slower websites (or when something is taking up most of your bandwidth)